# Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

Tags: node.js

I'm having problems with Ionic Serve, I get the following error message (please note everything was working until i had to kill a session using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then it started coming up with this error:

```
    Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
```

To attempt to resolve this I've :

1. Used the command npm rebuild node-sass --force
2. deleted node-sass directory and ran sudo npm install
3. deleted the entire node modules directory and reinstalled everything using sudo npm install

Any help would greatly appreciated. Based on other posts, it looks like for most people one of the above options worked. Just not for me.

I'm running Linux Ubuntu, and I haven't touched my node versions :

```
       v6.12.2
->      v7.10.1
         system
default -> 7.10.1 (-> v7.10.1)
node -> stable (-> v7.10.1) (default)
stable -> 7.10 (-> v7.10.1) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/carbon (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.8.7 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.12.2
lts/carbon -> v8.9.3 (-> N/A)
```

NPM Version is 4.2.0.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue but it was because I had:
node v11.4.0 on my machine and I was using an older node version via nvm in my project repository (10.13.x). The work around I found is:

`cd node_modules` and then 
`npm rebuild node-sass`

and this should work because node-sass has a postscript that runs in the previous directory above the directory that you are in. I configured my nvm in such a way that it installs node versions in my project directory. So for instance, if you are in project folder, and the directory above that would reference to node v11.4.0. But if I am in node_modules folder, when the postscript runs, it will run using v10.13.x since the previous directory is your project folder, which is where nvm installed my target node version.

I am working on a better solution to globalize my node versions instead of installing in my project directory...

hope this helps though

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems, that you have a `binding.node` for `nodejs v8` and currently you are using `nodejs v7`. Normally anywhere in the error message you can see which `binding.node` is needed.

You could try to download the `binding.node` for your environment by yourself (from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases) and put it into the `npm-cache/node-sass/vX.X.X` folder and then repeat your steps you already did.

Comment: Thank you, how do I work out which one to download ?

Comment: I don't know how to get this out. But I would go with the latest. And normally if you get an error then the error log shows you the name of the right binding node

Comment: After struggling with a few other solutions this was the hacky solution I needed :)